# Calling an external program in Perl under Windows and Linux and printing what it's doing live

Tags: perl

I am trying to call an external program, i.e. unrar, from Perl and allow for printing its output to screen while it is running.

```
@lin1=`cd "$wholepath_dir" & $laufwerk & unrar x -v -y "$_" ` if ($^O =~ /Win/) ;       

@lin1=`cd "$wholepath_dir"; unrar x -v -y "$_" ` if (not ($^O =~ /Win/)) ;
```

This code unrars some-rar-file.rar inside a directory.
However, it does not show any progress. 
It would be nice if it displayed the unrar output live, whilst unraring is happening, instead of feeding the unrar result to an array.

Any idea of how to do that, both for windows and linux?

Comment: Do need to capture the output too or do you only want to display it and foget it directly afterwards?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using `system()` rather than backticks to run the command?

Comment: I'd just want to display and forget it, but additionally capturing the output in an array whilst the thing is happening can't be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it: it lets the shell handle the redirection for STDERR. I don't have Windows, so I don't know what the corresponding bits in `cmd.exe` would be.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub run_command(\@$) {
    my($log, $cmd) = @_;

    my($redirect_start, $redirect_end);
    if ($^O =~ /Win/) {
        # @TODO
        $redirect_start = '???';
        $redirect_end   = '???';
    } else {
        $redirect_start = '(';
        $redirect_end   = ') 2>&1';
    }
    open(my $fh, "${redirect_start}${cmd}${redirect_end} |")
        or die "ERROR: $!\n";

    while (<$fh>) {
        push(@{ $log }, $_);
        print;
    }

    close($fh)
        or die "ERROR: $!\n";
}

my @log;
run_command(@log, 'ls dummy.*');
run_command(@log, 'ls -lht dummy.txt');

print "\nLOG:\n";
print foreach (@log);

exit 0;
```

Example output from my machine:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
dummy.c
dummy.c~
...
dummy.txt
dummy.txt~
dummy.xml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 USER USER 926 Jan 25 23:33 dummy.txt

LOG:
dummy.c
dummy.c~
...
dummy.txt
dummy.txt~
dummy.xml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 USER USER 926 Jan 25 23:33 dummy.txt
```

If the above solution isn't satisfactory, I would suggest to look into [IPC::Open3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open3).

Answer (score 1):

For interactive stuff like this, [`IPC::Run`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) is usually a good bet.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use IPC::Run qw/ run new_chunker /;

my @cmd = ('yourcommand', 'arg1', 'arg2');
my (@out,@err);
run \@cmd, '>', new_chunker("\n"), sub {
        my $line = shift;
        print $line;
        push @out, $line;
    }, '2>', new_chunker("\n"), sub {
        my $line = shift;
        print STDERR $line;
        push @err, $line;
    } or die $?;
```

*Copied from my post [here](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1210365). I also wrote about the topic of calling external commands, with example code, at length [here](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1180578).*

Answer (score 1):

First, note that surrounding something in quotes is not an effective way to protect it from shell parsing, since it could contain quotes itself. The best way is to avoid the shell parsing entirely by using the list form of open/system/open3/etc, but since you are using the shell metacharacter `&` you can't do this. So you can use [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote) to provide a string quoted for the appropriate shell.

Using [IPC::Open3](https://perldoc.pl/IPC::Open3):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Open3;
use String::ShellQuote;

my $quoted_dir = shell_quote $wholepath_dir;
my $quoted_file = shell_quote $_;
my $cmd = $^O =~ /Win/
  ? "cd $quoted_dir & $laufwerk & unrar x -v -y $quoted_file"
  : "cd $quoted_dir; unrar x -v -y $quoted_file";

my $pid = open3 undef, my $stdout, '>&STDERR', $cmd;
my @lines;
while (my $line = readline $stdout) {
  print $line;
  push @lines, $line;
}
waitpid $pid, 0;
my $exit_code = $? >> 8;
# you can now act on the $exit_code and the @lines of STDOUT
```

Answer (score 1):

To just display the progress and forget it afterwards, except any errors, was finally fine for me, and I solved it the following way, but for windows only :

```
@lin1=`start cd "$wholepath_dir" ^& $laufwerk ^& unrar x -v -y "$_" ^&^& exit ^& ( Echo ERROR_FAILED ^> $lockfile ^& timeout 3 ^& exit ) ` if ($^O =~ /Win/) ;
```

This opens a subshell so another cmd.exe pops up, shows the whole unrar process, closes immidately if it went fine or pauses 3 additional seconds and writes an error message to a "lockfile" if something went wrong.
Later the size of the lockfile is checked so the main program knows if an error happened or not. Then, the lockfile is deleted.

I guess there is no such solution for Linux then?